# Is there a class containing statics for algorithm names/modes/paddings?

Tags: java, encryption, javax.crypto

If I needed to reference an encoding, like UTF-8, I'd typically reference the `StandardCharset.UTF-8` static, not use a String literal `"UTF-8"`.

When working with cipher transformations, I see everywhere that transformations are given as String literals, like `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` or `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")`, and occasionally, there's a typo.

Which class can I use for statics of cipher algorithm names, modes and paddings? Does one exist?

For reference, [list of permitted names/modes/paddings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher) in the docs.

Comment: I have never seen these defined as constants.  You can, of course, define them yourself in your own class.